# .Net Remoting server connection limit

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

Is there a limit on the number of connection a .Net Remoting server can handle?

Comment: I don't think there is an explicit limit (possibly something you can tune in a configuration file). But .NET Remoting is deprecated, WCF is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't be too eager to recommend WCF over Remoting. WCF is much more complex than Remoting, and most of this complexity stems from being modeled around SOAP messaging - and I don't see why I should deal with the complexities of the SOAP messaging model if I don't plan on providing a SOAP web service. Besides, the SOAP model is semi-deprecated itself, ASP.NET MVC Web API is the way to go for .NET web services these days.

Comment: Then, on the other hand, MS officially deprecated Remoting, as you rightly pointed out - which puts you between a rock and a hard place if you just want to do simple, non-web, client-server communication.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of server.

If it is a "Single Call" server then for each request the remoting infrastructure creates a new instance of the server object on a new thread. The thread is taken from a thread pool which in .net usually contains around 25 threads.

It may also depend on the type of underlying transport TCp or HTTP which have thier own limitations.

And one more possiblity will be the limitations imposed by the operating system itself concerning remote connections to a machine (on TCP channel for instance).